# pangres python: IndexError: All index levels must be named

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I would like to do an upsert in my sql database using "pangres",
however it returns this error

```
raise IndexError("All index levels must be named!")
IndexError: All index levels must be named!
```

what should I do?

```
df = pd.read_excel('personne.xlsx')
upsert(engine=engine,
       df=df,
       table_name='personne',
       if_row_exists='update')
```

Answer (score 2):

Name the df index or set a column as the index. See [the Pangres wiki](https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres/wiki/Upsert).

For dfs with `df['unique_id']` to use as the primary key:

```py
# create SQL table with first df, set if_exists as needed
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists = 'fail', index = False)

with engine.connect() as con: # set df['unique_id'] as primary key in SQL
    con.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (unique_id);")

# set df2['unique_id'] as index
df2.set_index(['unique_id'], inplace = True, drop = False)
pangres.upsert(engine, df2, 'table_name', if_row_exists ='update')
```